# Layering images using CSS and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a webpage, where I am wanting to layer 3 images accordingly to act as a backgound so content can be placed on top. The images shouldn't move when scrolling, so fixed position wouldn't work.
Below is the sequential order they should appear from back to front (1-3)

1. img - sky.jpg which I set as the background image in the html.
2. img - backDrop.png which is set above the sky.jpg.
3. img - BtmRight.png which I want to position above all images and bottom right.

Both images (backDrop.png, BtmRight.png)are set with absolute positioning and z-index to determine order.
I cant get BtmRight.png image to appear bottom right above other images. I want the bottom right image to stay in place when you scroll the page. I would also like the content to appear over all the images.
Below is my HTML/CSS, Is there something I'm missing?

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            </head>
            <style type="text/css">
            html {
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              margin-top:100px;
              background: url(sky.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
               background-size: cover;
            }
            body {
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
            }
            #imgBack {
                width: 100%;
                margin-top:100px;
                position:absolute;
                z-index:20;
                border:#0FF thin solid;
            }
            #imgBtmRight {
                position:absolute; 
                z-index:50; 
                bottom:0; 
                right:0;
            }
            </style>

            <body>

            <img id="imgBtmRight" src="BtmRight.png" width="413" height="283" /> 



            <img id="imgBack" src="backDrop.png" />

            </body>
            </html>
```

Any light on the subject, or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @user1588253: Ask better questions. Or better said, edit your questions and leave comments to further explain the problem you're having.

Comment: Sigh. The answer below is a perfect example: @massivepenguin put a ton of effort into addressing the question and never got his answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a good idea to stack your DOM elements in the right order (as well as closing that div):

1. body
2. Backdrop
3. BtmRight
4. Content

The natural 'stacking' is bottom to top - think of each element (image, div, etc.) as a piece of paper. As you move down the HTML document, you add pieces of paper to the stack. The papers sit on top of each other, unless you change the z-indexing explicitly - but it's best to get them in the right order to begin with, if you can.

Edit:

Seems to be working:

[Example using linked images](http://jsfiddle.net/2jCJw/)

The only things I changed were the image sources and positioning on the body tag. Unless there's something else you've missed out of the code you should have no problem.

ANOTHER Edit:

If you want the bottom-right image to stay in place, use position: fixed on that image rather than position: absolute.

YET ANOTHER Edit:

If you want the content to go over the top of the bottom-right image, you just need to add a wrapper for your content and use z-indexing:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2jCJw/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the stack order, swapped the images around backDrop first and then BtmRight, but still not working.

Comment: Try adding position: relative to your body tag too.

Comment: @MassivePenquin, thanks for the assistance. I checked the example, the image of the cat doesn't stay at the bottom if you scroll, that's exactly what I have.

Comment: That isn't what you asked. Rephrase your question please!

Comment: You can get the bottom-right image to stay in place if you change position: absolute to position:fixed, by the way.

Comment: I tried that, the only thing is the image is fixed and when you scroll it overlaps content because of it's fixed position, is there no other way of doing it?

Comment: Again, that isn't what you asked; you didn't mention that you wanted content to appear over the top of the image. You'll keep getting incomplete answers unless you ask clearer questions ;)

Comment: Apologies if I'm being unclear, the images are to be like background images so that content can be placed on top such text etc. The images must be absolutely positioned and not move when scrolling etc.

Comment: Updated my answer again. If you don't want the images to move at all, use position: fixed. Then you can add a relatively-positioned div with your content in. As long as your z-indexing is right, that should sort your problem. Unless you've left anything else out ;)

Comment: OK, close but still not, If I fix the images. the backDrop image is cut off and is fixed at that height, see site http://www.theedgekzn.co.za/

Comment: What (exactly) do you want the backDrop image to do? You keep contradicting yourself. If you want it to scroll with the content, then use position: absolute.

Comment: I'm not contradicting what I'm saying, you misunderstanding. I think my best option is to just merge the bottom right image to the backdrop image which will solve the issue, I just thought css would be flexible enough to handle it. Basically the sky image is to stretch to what ever resolution, the back drop image has a fixed height and must not be stretched or cut off and the bottomRight image should stay at the bottom right, with none of the images moving/scrolling i.e. to be a conjoined background image. and to be able to place content such as text above all these images.

Comment: That isn't what you asked, but I'm not going to get into an argument. It's still not clear what you're trying to do, but if you want the backDrop image to scroll, use position: relative instead (http://jsfiddle.net/2jCJw/4/). If you don't want it to stretch, take out the width: 100% part as that will always stretch it. The drawback is that if your content is taller than the backDrop image then you will see a blank space. If this isn't right, then the only way you'll get around this is by using Javascript.